# Can Rust code compile without the standard library?

Tags: rust

I'm currently in the progress of learning Rust. I'm mainly using [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) book and [this nice reference](https://github.com/nrc/r4cppp) which relates Rust features/syntax to C++ equivalents.

I'm having a hard time understanding where the core language stops and the standard library starts. I've encountered a lot of operators and/or traits which seems to have a special relationship with the compiler. For example, Rust has a `trait` (which from what I understand is like an interface) called `Deref` which let's a type implementing it be de-referenced using the `*` operator:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let y = Box::new(x);

    assert_eq!(5, x);
    assert_eq!(5, *y);
}
```

Another example is the `?` operator, which seems to depend on the `Result` and `Option` types.

Can code that uses those operators can be compiled without the standard library? And if not, what parts of the Rust language are depending on the standard library? Is it even possible to compile *any* Rust code without it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Rust standard library is in fact separated into three distinct crates:

- [`core`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/index.html), which is the glue between the language and the standard library. All types, traits and functions *required* by the language are found in this crate. This includes operator traits (found in [`core::ops`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/ops/index.html)), the [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/future/trait.Future.html) trait (used by `async fn`), and [compiler intrinsics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/intrinsics/index.html). The `core` crate does not have *any* dependencies, so you can always use it.
- [`alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/index.html), which contains types and traits related to or requiring dynamic memory allocation. This includes dynamically allocated types such as `Box<T>`, `Vec<T>` and `String`.
- [`std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/index.html), which contains the whole standard library, including things from `core` and `alloc` but also things with further requirements, such as file system access, networking, etc.

If your environment does not provide the functionality required by the `std` crate, you can choose to compile without it. If your environment also does not provide dynamic memory allocation, you can choose to compile without the `alloc` crate as well. This option is useful for targets such as embedded systems or writing operating systems, where you usually won't have all of the things that the standard library usually requires.

You can use the [`#![no_std]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/no-stdlib.html) attribute in the root of your crate to tell the compiler to compile without the standard library (only `core`). Many libraries also usually support "no-`std`" compilation (e.g. [`base64`](https://crates.io/crates/base64) and [`futures`](https://crates.io/crates/base64)), where functionality may be restricted but it will work when compiling without the `std` crate.

Answer (score 5):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is likely not the answer you're looking for. Consider reading the other answers about `no_std`, if you're trying to solve a problem. I suggest you only read on, if you're interested in trivia about the inner workings of Rust.

If you really want full control over the environment you use, it is possible to use Rust without the `core` library using the `no_core` attribute.
If you decide to do so, you will run into some problems, because the compiler is integrated with some items defined in `core`.
This integration works by applying the `#[lang = "..."]` attribute to those items, making them so called "lang items".
If you use `no_core`, you'll have to define your own lang items for the parts of the language you'll actually use.
For more information I suggest the following blog posts, which go into more detail on the topic of lang items and `no_core`:

- [Rust Tidbits: What Is a Lang Item?](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/11/rust-tidbits-what-is-a-lang-item/)
- [Oxidizing the technical interview](https://dev.to/mgattozzi/oxidizing-the-technical-interview-32ni)

So yes, in theory it is possible to run Rust code without **any** sort of standard library and supplied types, but only if you then supply the required types yourself.
Also this is not stable and will likely never be stabilized and it is generally not a recommended way of using Rust.

Answer (score 4):

When you're not using `std`, you rely on [`core`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/), which is a subset of the `std` library which is always (?) available. This is what's called a `no_std` environment, which is commonly used for some types of "embedded" programming. You can find more about [`no_std`](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/intro/no-std.html) in the Rust Embedded book, including some guidance on [how to get started](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/start/qemu.html) with `no_std` programming.